# Is it possible to create Raphael drawing panel dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, raphael, createelement

I am working with raphael.js, my question is: Is it possible to generate
a raphael drawing panel dynamically with a button? So far I've tried to
do that with createElement but it did not work.

Here is script using raphael.js

```
var g_masterPathArray;
var g_masterDrawingBox;
var g_masterPaper;

function initDrawing() {
    var g_masterPaper = Raphael(10, 10, 700, 500);

    var masterBackground = g_masterPaper.rect(10, 10, 600, 400);
    masterBackground.attr("fill", "#eee");
    masterBackground.mousemove(function (event) {
        var evt = event;
        var IE = document.all ? true : false;
        var x, y;
        if (IE) {
            x = evt.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
            document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            y = evt.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
            document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        else {
            x = evt.pageX;
            y = evt.pageY;
        }

        // subtract paper coords on page
        this.ox = x - 10;
        this.oy = y - 10;
    });

    var start = function () {
        g_masterPathArray = new Array();
    },
    move = function (dx, dy) {
        if (g_masterPathArray.length == 0) {
            g_masterPathArray[0] = ["M", this.ox, this.oy];
            g_masterDrawingBox = g_masterPaper.path(g_masterPathArray);
            g_masterDrawingBox.attr({ stroke: "#000000", "stroke-width": 3 });
        }
        else
            g_masterPathArray[g_masterPathArray.length] = ["L", this.ox, this.oy];

        g_masterDrawingBox.attr({ path: g_masterPathArray });
    },
    up = function () {
        ;
    };

    masterBackground.drag(move, start, up);
    return g_masterPaper;
}
```

I've defined a `generate()` function but I am not sure about the
elements that I have to create so far. Any ideas?

Comment: What is a drawing panel? Do you mean a paper? You're creating one roght there in the `initDrawing` function.

Comment: yes I meant paper the thing that we draw things on.. I need to generate that paper when a button clicked .. Is that possible

Comment: Like this? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Also I've tried calling initDrawing fuction on a button's onclick but it did not work too

Comment: No , like that http://jsfiddle.net/regeme/xNSVm/ when you click generate a new canvas generated as you see.. I want the same action on raphael paper

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

html:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Clear" />
<input type="button" id="generate" value="Generate" />
```

js:

```
function generate(){
var self = this;
    self.CurrentFreeID = 0;
    self.newCanvas = {};
    self.Papers = [];
    self.Container = document.getElementById('container');
    self.doGenerate = function (){
        self.newCanvas = document.createElement('div');
        self.Container.appendChild(self.newCanvas);
        self.newCanvas.id  = 'someID'+self.CurrentFreeID.toString();

        self.Papers.push(Raphael(self.newCanvas.id,200,200));
        self.Papers[ self.CurrentFreeID].rect(10,10,10,10);
        self.CurrentFreeID++;
    };
    self.Init=function (){
        document.getElementById('generate').onclick = self.doGenerate;
    };
}

var gener = new generate();
gener.Init();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xNSVm/4/

Comment: Hey thanks for interest but When I click generate only small boxes displayed that I couldnt draw anything.. I couldn catch the point ..

Comment: I thought that you wanted ust to create raphael papers dynamically, from your comment I understand that u want to have drawing implementation in the raphael. It should not be that hard to implement tough. Just create path and append to its path attribute your current cursor position (relative to the paper) in this format " L "+ CurrentPosX + "," + CurrentPosY;